# SSIS Package - Load CSV File with Pipe (|) as Delimiter

Tags: csv, ssis

I am trying to load a .csv file into an MS SQL table using an SSIS package. My file has comma(,) as part of data so I changed the delimiter to pipe(|). I am using double quotes(") as the text qualifier. Now, there is another row causing failure of the package.

```
Person ID|Preferred Name|Last Name|First Name|Title
1111|"John "O.H." Doe"|"Doe"|"John"|"Unknown, Undisclosed"
2222|"Jon Snow"|"Stark"|"Jon Snow"|"The White Wolf"
```

I don't have any issues with Jon Snow but John Doe is killing me.

```
[Flat File Source [8]] Error: The column delimiter for column "Preferred Name" was not found.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your data has the text delimiter within it and it is not escaped. `"John "O.H." Doe"`

Unless your data naturally has a pipe in it and it sounds like you have control over the file format, just set the delimiter as `|` and no text delimiter and call it good.

Your source data should then look like the following and all will be good

```
Person ID|Preferred Name|Last Name|First Name|Title
1111|John "O.H." Doe|Doe|John|Unknown, Undisclosed
2222|Jon Snow|Stark|Jon Snow|The White Wolf
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I checked in excel file and sure enough, it has (") as part of the cell value. But if I ignore text qualifier, my SQL table got loaded with double quotes around all the data, which I don't want. How to handle that?

Comment: Thank you! actually I don't have control over the file format. I will reach out to my customer to see if they can change the file generation process on their end.